# Write Node.js code to receive HTTP calls that initialize and update objects stored in JSON files

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express.js

This is a backend side of Node.js running a simple Http endpoints for a monitring system for a time-related task

I recently developed a habit that I would rather spend time to make the code as less as possible because I consider neat looking code is art. I'm lazy to come up with a name for variables and functions, for example, I use alphabet as variable or parameters, and also if any part of the code that duplicate, I'd put them into functions or variables

> main.js

```
const lib=require('./lib')
const express=require("express")
const app=express()

const multer=require('multer')
const upload=multer()

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
  next()
})

const veri=require('./veri')

app.get('/veri',veri.run.show)
app.post('/veri',upload.fields([]),async(req,res)=>{
    await veri.run.update(req.body.a)
    res.send('ok')
})

const clock=require('./clock')

app.get('/clock',clock.run.show)
app.post('/clock',upload.fields([]),clock.run.update)
app.get('/sche',clock.run.sche)

app.listen(3001)
```

> clock.js

```
const lib=require('./lib')
const path='json/clock.json'

const init=async()=>{
    const a=await lib.bb(path)
    a.forEach((x,i)=>{
        if(x==1) a[i]=0
    })
    lib.json2txt(path,a)
}

//init()

const show=async(req,res)=>{
    const a=await lib.bb(path)
    res.send(a)
}

//show('',{send:console.log})

const update=async(req,res)=>{
    const a=await lib.bb(path)
    a[req.body.a]=1
    lib.json2txt(path,a)
    res.send('Done')
}

const sche=async(req,res)=>{
    const a=await lib.bb(path)
    a[req.query.a]=2
    lib.json2txt(path,a)
    init()
    res.send('Done')
}

const mock={
    req:{
        body:{
            a:3
        },
        query:{
            a:0
        }
    }
}

//update(mock.req,{send:console.log})
//sche(mock.req,{send:console.log})

lib.wrapcron('init','55 23 * * 0,1-5',init)

exports.run={update,show,sche}
```

> veri.js

```
const lib=require('./lib')
const path='json/veri.json'

const update=async k=>{
    const a=await lib.bb(path)
    a[k]=+new Date
    lib.json2txt(path,a)
}

const show=async(req,res)=>{
    const b=await lib.bb(path)
    res.send(b)
}

//show('',{send:console.log})
//update('soAg')

exports.run={update,show}
```

> lib.js

```
const fs=require('fs')

exports.t=msg=>console.log(`[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] ${msg}`)

exports.json2txt=(fullPath,json)=>{
  fs.writeFile(fullPath,JSON.stringify(json),err=>{
    if(err) exports.t(err)
    else exports.t(`wrote to ${fullPath}`)
  })
}

const txt2json=(fullpath,callback)=>{
  fs.readFile(fullpath,'utf-8',(err,res)=>{
    if(err) exports.t(err)
    else callback(JSON.parse(res))
  })
}

const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob
console.t=msg=>console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()} ${msg}`)

exports.wrapcron=(name,cron,f)=>{
  const job = new CronJob(cron, ()=>{
    console.t(`Job ${name} is running`)
    f()
  }, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles')
  job.start()
  console.t(`Crontab ${name} scheduled: ${cron}`)
}

exports.bb=path=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  txt2json(path,resolve)
})
```

Comment: The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).